# How to pass an array to Joomla session correctly

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, session

I use the following code to pass an array to session:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$itemid = $input->get('id');
$quan = $input->get('quan');
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$cart = array();
$cart['items'][] = array('id' => $itemid, 'quan' => $quan);
$session->set('cart', $cart);
```

It passes data of one item successfully, but when I try to add one more item to the session the code doesn't add it as a new item but overwrites existed item by new item. How to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get your existing data from session, modify it and push it back into the session.

Replace

```
$cart = array();
```

with

```
$cart = $session->get('cart', array());
```